# Book/series where people were implanted with a power giving stone after birth

Tags: story-identification

The only vivid memory I have of this book is that the citizens of the story's world are all associated with a certain element, such as air or water, etc. This association brings them powers that can control that particular element. The powers, though, can only be enhanced/ used if 'special stones' are implanted in their spine after birth.

The stones themselves are plain, but once implanted in a baby's back, they turn a certain color. The stones are implanted in a special ritual performed by alien-like creatures, who are very powerful.

I have a feeling it was a part of a series, but I am unsure.

I just remembered something else. The stones are very expensive and the parents have to save up in order to afford them. Multiple stones can be implanted in one person and the number of stones implanted in a person indicates the amount of power they have.

Comment: Its like Avatar meets Captain Planet.

Comment: I know right? I remember the book being pretty darn interesting. Wish I could get my hands on it.

Comment: Is it a relatively recent series or something you read decades ago?

Comment: I read this about 9-10 years ago. And I have a feeling it isn't from like tolkien times, relatively more recent.

Comment: I just know I've read the same book as you!
It was definitely a series by the way.
Two main characters a brother and sister both with like 5 stones in their spine.
There were also monsters/assasination type creature on the side of the bad guys who could travel through mirrors/any reflective surface.
Their dad got killed in front of them and they joined this rebel alliance type thing.
It was a really interesting series wish i remembered the name of it >.<

Comment: Well twist my nips and call me Bongo. Finally, I've found someone looking for the same book (series) as me, and an answer, too. It's been pestering me in the back of my head for years, and today I just couldn't take it anymore. I'm sooo glad you've helped me find it :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like the [Broken Sky series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_Sky) by [Chris Wooding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Wooding), which began publication by Scholastic in 2000. More information is available on [the author's website](http://www.chriswooding.com/the-books/broken-sky/).

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I had read only one book when I was a kid, and remember being disappointed as my library didn't have the rest of the series. You have made my day! :)