# YA novel series about kids with elemental powers

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

The following is a list of elements I remember about this book series:

1)  The cover art was very anime inspired, but was clearly an American or Canadian series.

2)  Wyverns were involved.  Not dragons, wyverns (dragons have forearms, wyverns have wings where their forearms should be).

3)  The people in this world had the ability to control elements, provided that they had special stones implanted in their backs.

4)  The main characters both had 6 of these stones implanted in their backs (most people could only afford 1 or 2 stones for their children).

5)  The main characters were twins (a boy and a girl).  The girl had the power to control earth, and I cannot recall what the boy could control.

6)  The boy sucked at controlling his power.

This is all that I can remember.  I must have read these books somewhere around 2002-2005, and they seemed reasonably new at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Broken Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_Sky)* as per [Book/series where people were implanted with a power giving stone after birth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4508/23243)

> While the societies in Broken Sky rely on various infrastructures for their survival, such as water or Tusami City's magma-based geothermal power, one commodity which appears to rule many facets of daily life is the Spirit Stone. Extracted by mining as an inert, colourless gemstone, the Spirit Stones only take on their characteristic colour after being implanted by a Deliverer during a ritualistic ceremony called the pah'nu'kah.
>
> During the ritual, the Spirit Stones are implanted along the spine - specifically, in the voids between their vertebrae - of a newborn child, being partially phased into their bodies so that only one hemisphere is visible. Once the ritual is complete, both the stones and the child forge a connection with the ley lines - conduits of raw energy running beneath the earth - giving the stones a specific colour and the child command over a certain ability later in life.
>
> With the stones themselves being incredibly expensive, possessing multiple Spirit Stones is often a defining trait of the wealthy but, despite this, people in the Dominions possess an average of two or three stones a piece. Being a renowned wyvern-breeder, Banto purchased a grand total of eighteen Spirit Stones; six for each of his children. Although "financially crippling", the power Ryushi, Kia and Takami have at their disposal is vastly in excess of the majority of people.

And indeed, [Kia controls earth and Ryushi has difficulty controlling his power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Broken_Sky_characters).

Comment: Welp, my eyes are spinning.  Fantastic job Fuzzy